# RPC - conflicting types error

Tags: c, linux, rpc

I have the following .x file called paper.x . When I create a server in rpc in order to call the function the error below occurs

**paperserverproc.c:23:5: error: conflicting types for ‘add_procedure_1_svc’
paper.h:46:15: note: previous declaration of ‘add_procedure_1_svc’ was here**

```
#include <limits.h>
struct paper_saved{
    char author_name[CHAR_MAX];
    char paper_title[CHAR_MAX];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[CHAR_MAX]; 
    char  paper_content[CHAR_MAX];   
};
struct paper_info_saved{
    char author_name[CHAR_MAX];
    char paper_title[CHAR_MAX];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[CHAR_MAX]; 

};
struct list_papers{
    paper_saved paper;
    struct list_papers *next; 
}; 

program PAPER_PROGRAM
{
  version PAPER_VERSION
  {
    int ADD_PROCEDURE(paper_saved) = 1;        /* Procedure nb */
    void LIST_PROCEDURE(void)=2;
    paper_info_saved INFO_PROCEDURE(int)=3;
    paper_saved FETCH_PROCEDURE(int)=4;
    void REMOVE_PROCEDURE(int)=5;
   } = 1;                             /* Version nb */
} = 0x20001234;                      /* Program number */
```

I call the procedure with this way and the line 23 is the line when I declare the function as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "paper.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
.......
int add_procedure_1_svc(paper_saved *paper_pointer, struct svc_req *rqstp)
```

This is the paper.h file generated by rpcgen and I dont know what's the problem in line 46 that it mentions

```
 /*
 * Please do not edit this file.
 * It was generated using rpcgen.
 */

#ifndef _PAPER_H_RPCGEN
#define _PAPER_H_RPCGEN

#include <rpc/rpc.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
 #endif


struct paper_saved {
    char author_name[127];
    char paper_title[127];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[127];
     char paper_content[127];
};
typedef struct paper_saved paper_saved;

struct paper_info_saved {
    char author_name[127];
    char paper_title[127];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[127];
};
typedef struct paper_info_saved paper_info_saved;

struct list_papers {
    paper_saved paper;
     struct list_papers *next;
};
typedef struct list_papers list_papers;

#define PAPER_PROGRAM 0x20001234
#define PAPER_VERSION 1

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define ADD_PROCEDURE 1
extern  int * add_procedure_1(paper_saved *, CLIENT *);
extern  int * add_procedure_1_svc(paper_saved *, struct svc_req *);
#define LIST_PROCEDURE 2
extern  void * list_procedure_1(void *, CLIENT *);
extern  void * list_procedure_1_svc(void *, struct svc_req *);
#define INFO_PROCEDURE 3
extern  paper_info_saved * info_procedure_1(int *, CLIENT *);
extern  paper_info_saved * info_procedure_1_svc(int *, struct svc_req *);
#define FETCH_PROCEDURE 4
extern  paper_saved * fetch_procedure_1(int *, CLIENT *);
extern  paper_saved * fetch_procedure_1_svc(int *, struct svc_req *);
#define REMOVE_PROCEDURE 5
extern  void * remove_procedure_1(int *, CLIENT *);
extern  void * remove_procedure_1_svc(int *, struct svc_req *);
extern int paper_program_1_freeresult (SVCXPRT *, xdrproc_t, caddr_t);

#else /* K&R C */
#define ADD_PROCEDURE 1
extern  int * add_procedure_1();
extern  int * add_procedure_1_svc();
#define LIST_PROCEDURE 2
extern  void * list_procedure_1();
extern  void * list_procedure_1_svc();
#define INFO_PROCEDURE 3
extern  paper_info_saved * info_procedure_1();
extern  paper_info_saved * info_procedure_1_svc();
#define FETCH_PROCEDURE 4
extern  paper_saved * fetch_procedure_1();
extern  paper_saved * fetch_procedure_1_svc();
#define REMOVE_PROCEDURE 5
extern  void * remove_procedure_1();
extern  void * remove_procedure_1_svc();
extern int paper_program_1_freeresult ();
#endif /* K&R C */

/* the xdr functions */

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern  bool_t xdr_paper_saved (XDR *, paper_saved*);
extern  bool_t xdr_paper_info_saved (XDR *, paper_info_saved*);
extern  bool_t xdr_list_papers (XDR *, list_papers*);

#else /* K&R C */
extern bool_t xdr_paper_saved ();
extern bool_t xdr_paper_info_saved ();
extern bool_t xdr_list_papers ();

#endif /* K&R C */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* !_PAPER_H_RPCGEN */
```

So the correct one .h file is

```
#include <limits.h>
struct paper_saved{
    char author_name[CHAR_MAX];
    char paper_title[CHAR_MAX];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[CHAR_MAX]; 
    char  paper_content[CHAR_MAX];   
};
struct paper_info_saved{
    char author_name[CHAR_MAX];
    char paper_title[CHAR_MAX];
    int paper_id;
    char paper_file_name[CHAR_MAX]; 

};
struct list_papers{
    paper_saved paper;
    struct list_papers *next; 
}; 
typedef int p_id;
program PAPER_PROGRAM
{
  version PAPER_VERSION
  {
    p_id ADD_PROCEDURE(paper_saved) = 1;        /* Procedure nb */
    void LIST_PROCEDURE(void)=2;
    paper_info_saved INFO_PROCEDURE(int)=3;
    paper_saved FETCH_PROCEDURE(int)=4;
    void REMOVE_PROCEDURE(int)=5;
   } = 1;                             /* Version nb */
} = 0x20001234;                      /* Program number */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is declared as returning `int`:

```
int add_procedure_1_svc(paper_saved *paper_pointer, struct svc_req *rqstp)
```

but the `extern` as returning `int*`

```
extern  int * add_procedure_1_svc(paper_saved *, struct svc_req *);
```

one of them must be wrong.

Comment: Man that's the problem! you are right! i should add a lin in the .h file typedef int p_id and set p_id as the return of the procedure. Thanks! @BinyaminSharet

Answer (score 0):

What does line 46 of file paper.h have? . Check the paper.h file on the line 46 to see if the function signature is same.Is it auto generated by rpcgen ?

Comment: I have added the paper.h file generated by rpcgen. If you could find the problem man I would be greatful. @RanjithRuban